# Is it possible in a forest plot all negative confidence intervals sum to a positive range,?

Tags: confidence-interval, meta-analysis, forest-plot

[image: rest plot]

For example in that case, all confidence intervals are negative BUT the sum is in positive range (-37.62 to 0.5), which I don't understand. If there is anybody knows the explanation I would be appreciate that!

Comment: It makes perfectly sense. The Wilder et al study is precise and close to the 0 line, so it forces the overall effect estimates (in terms of 95% confidence interval) beyond (albeit slightly) 0. I would double check the way SD was estimated, as the bottom line is you have huge variability and inconsistency.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! I get the point. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in a comment

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues here.

First of all it is perfectly possible in a situation where you have high heterogeneity to have a wide confidence interval for the mean of the underlying distribution of effects sizes. In this case that happens to include the null even though none of the individual studies does. In fact if you use REML to estimate $\tau^2$ instead of DerSimonian and Laird (which I assume you are using) the confidence interval just fails to include the null.

If you use a prediction interval which gives you the limits for a new study this has bounds -55.8 to 18.7 which are much wider.

You are modelling using the scale of raw means. This seems frankly quite hard to believe here. You have studies returning a mean of 13.7, 355, and 47.7 for the control group. The assumption that these are all being measured on a common scale seems difficult to explain.

Comment: Is there any way to apply REML on this analysis? How?

Comment: The interpretation is perfectly right! Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean standard mean difference?

Comment: Standardised mean differences are what people usually use if the studies have used different scales.